# F#, Visual Studio 2017 and dotnet new

Tags: f#, .net-core

To create a .NET class library from the command line, you can run the script

```
dotnet new classlib
```

Do that in a clean folder, and it will create a `csproj` file that can then be opened in Visual Studio 2017.

However, run the script

```
dotnet new classlib -lang f#
```

in a clean folder, and the fsproj file that is subsequently create cannot be opened in Visual Studio 2017. The error message reads

> The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\FSharp.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I have searched for clarification of this issue, and it appears that there is work ongoing to fix it, but I wondered in the interim if there are any add-ins I can install to get this working immediately.

Comment: vscode + ionide works well for F# .net core development

Comment: This has been a major pain-in-the-neck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The latest preview releases of Visual Studio and .NET Core support loading .fsproj projects, apparently.

[See this comment on the GitHub issue:](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/2316#issuecomment-312155688)

> Closing this now, as these projects load with 15.3. The current way to use them:
>
> - Download VS 2017 Update 3 Preview 3 (or a further preview if it's released and you're reading this)
> - Download the latest CLI/SDK from here: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/tree/release/2.0.0#installers-and-binaries
>
> (Yes, the .NET SDK is independent of VS. You will also need this to get .NET Core 2.0 support in VS 2017 Update 3 Previews).

Comment: I was having the same problem I followed the instruction and was able to advance but just a little.
The project opens on VS2017 but no reference is show, most of the folder are invisible, and when I try to compile from VS2017 i get an exception saying that the 'Compile' itens are duplicated. 
Any tip?

Comment: @Destino: No idea, I'm afraid - I don't use Visual Studio much myself. I'd recommend raising an issue on the [F# GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/) if it's not working for you.