# Unable to open .Net Core solution using VS 20017 Preview 2

Tags: f#, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am unable to open the following [solution](https://github.com/Lambda-Cartel/Nikeza/tree/master/Server) using VS 20017 Preview 2.

Within solution explorer, the FSharp projects are displayed as incompatible.

I have the following version installed:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 Preview (2)
Version 15.3.0 Preview 6.0
VisualStudio.15.Preview/15.3.0-pre.6.0+26724.1
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.02046

Installed Version: Community
```

The solution file is the following:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 15
VisualStudioVersion = 15.0.26124.0
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 15.0.26124.0
Project("{6EC3EE1D-3C4E-46DD-8F32-0CC8E7565705}") = "Nikeza.Server", "Nikeza.Server/Nikeza.Server.fsproj", "{A608ADDA-8C89-4EB3-A739-D2BF5DA7CE9E}"
EndProject
Project("{6EC3EE1D-3C4E-46DD-8F32-0CC8E7565705}") = "video-youtube", "video-youtube\video-youtube.fsproj", "{30D28C83-97B8-4FA5-8D99-EC27E4CFF0E3}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Debug|x64 = Debug|x64
        Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
        Release|x64 = Release|x64
        Release|x86 = Release|x86
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {A608ADDA-8C89-4EB3-A739-D2BF5DA7CE9E}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {A608ADDA-8C89-4EB3-A739-D2BF5DA7CE9E}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {A608ADDA-8C89-4EB3-A739-D2BF5DA7CE9E}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {A608ADDA-8C89-4EB3-A739-D2BF5DA7CE9E}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {A608ADDA-8C89-4EB3-A739-D2BF5DA7CE9E}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {A608ADDA-8C89-4EB3-A739-D2BF5DA7CE9E}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86
        {A608ADDA-8C89-4EB3-A739-D2BF5DA7CE9E}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {A608ADDA-8C89-4EB3-A739-D2BF5DA7CE9E}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {A608ADDA-8C89-4EB3-A739-D2BF5DA7CE9E}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {A608ADDA-8C89-4EB3-A739-D2BF5DA7CE9E}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {A608ADDA-8C89-4EB3-A739-D2BF5DA7CE9E}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
        {A608ADDA-8C89-4EB3-A739-D2BF5DA7CE9E}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|x86
        {E6E142E5-6247-45C7-A375-9C9A74E249AE}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {E6E142E5-6247-45C7-A375-9C9A74E249AE}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {E6E142E5-6247-45C7-A375-9C9A74E249AE}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {E6E142E5-6247-45C7-A375-9C9A74E249AE}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {E6E142E5-6247-45C7-A375-9C9A74E249AE}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {E6E142E5-6247-45C7-A375-9C9A74E249AE}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86
        {E6E142E5-6247-45C7-A375-9C9A74E249AE}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {E6E142E5-6247-45C7-A375-9C9A74E249AE}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {E6E142E5-6247-45C7-A375-9C9A74E249AE}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {E6E142E5-6247-45C7-A375-9C9A74E249AE}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {E6E142E5-6247-45C7-A375-9C9A74E249AE}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
        {E6E142E5-6247-45C7-A375-9C9A74E249AE}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|x86
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327902/f-visual-studio-2017-and-dotnet-new

Comment: That's majorly due to change in approach across VS versions mostly. VS 2015 used to have project.json approach - that's no more valid in VS 2017.

Comment: Still can't open solution in VS. =(